# How to add multiple python expressions in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

How would I add multiple python expressions in the ArcMap Field Calculator if possible?

I tried separating each expression on a new line and also separating with a semi-colon but neither worked.

Here are the expressions I am trying to execute at once:

```
!field!.replace("+","")

'_'.join(num.zfill(4) for num in !field!.split('_'))

!field![:9]
```

Comment: You want to to do all these process on the same output field ? In this case you should do python function in the code bloc

Comment: Yes these are all on the same output field.  Do you have an example of how to turn these into a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am I correct in assuming you wish to carry out the operations in sequence i.e. the final value in the field comes from the !field![:9] operation?

If so, i would have the code block as:

```
def field_calc(field):
    str1 = field.replace("+","")
    str2 = "_".join([num.zfill(4) for num in str1.split('_')])
    str3 = str2[:9]
    return str3
```

Then call it using:

```
field_calc(!field!)
```

This will carry out each process in sequence, carrying the result forward. I haven't tested this since I don't have the data but I think it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In the code bloc :

```
def calcField(field):
 f1 = field.replace("+","")
 f2 = '_'.join(num.zfill(4) for num in field.split('_'))
 f3 = field[:9]
 return f1+f2+f3
```

in the expression line: calcField(!field!)

Comment: It looks like it ran 3 separate times since the text is repeated 3 times.  And it looks like only the second time ran correctly.